# Angular Promise not stopping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written the following promise in Angular but it doesn't seem to want to wait until the XHR data is returned.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
someAPICall.save({}, bigObject, function(data) {
            }).$promise.then(function(data) {
              //shouldn't it wait here for the data to be returned?
              qResponse = data;
            }, function(error) {
              console.log("error: " + error.status);
            })
```

Edit, here is the factory itself which uses $resource:

```
.factory("someAPICall", function($resource){
  var resource = $resource(serverPath + '/path/to/data', {}, {
    save: {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        //header info
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return resource;
})
```

Comment: if someAPICall.save(...).$promise gives you a promise than yes.

Comment: What's the `$promise` here? Couldn't find any info on it. Try and remove it (eg. write `someApiCall.save(...).then(...);` instead)

Comment: The so called waiting does not happen within then onFulfilled callback. The onFulfilled callback is called once the promise is fulfilled

Comment: Just .then doesn't work.  Returns someAPICall.save(...).then is not a function.  I wrote this function months ago and got the code from a page that was talking about an alternative to $q...that of course I can't find.

Comment: @JaromandaX so I've pretty much got to rewrite this whole thing?

Comment: No idea. Not enough info. I was trying to clear up a subtle misconception

Comment: What else can I tell you?

Comment: .save seems to use a callback. Which you've assigned an empty function. Use that. Or if .save returns a promise itself use that

Comment: Save just calls a POST method on the API...but you've given me a few things to try.

Comment: Added the factory to the above code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a stab in the dark here but it looks like you have an unnecessary callback function parameter in your call to `save`. (In this case it's even empty).

Lately I've been skipping promises all together when dealing with $resource because my applications haven't required any of the composability of dealing with multiple promises. For this reason I typically just use the success and failure handlers (you've got an empty success handler in your code).

Try this:

```
someAPICall.save({}, bigObject, function(successData) {
    // called asynchronously on success. No need for promises at all
}, function(errorData) {
    // called asynchronously on failure. No need for promises at all
});
```

Or alternatively (no idea if it will work) try getting the promise object without passing in a callback.

```
someAPICall.save({}, bigObject).$promise;
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks Jesse.